# Infinite sum of converging sequence is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I am trying to prove some statement about the nested sums, that is not that relevant here. Now, while trying to do so, I made a following hypothesis:
Let $(a_{n}(i))_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a real valued sequence for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$; that is $(a_1(i))_i, (a_2(i))_i, (a_3(i))_i... $ real valued sequence and suppose that

1. $\lim_{i\to \infty}a_n(i)= a_n$ (where $0\leq a_n<\infty$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$) and
2. $\lim_{i\to \infty} \sum_n a_n(i)<\infty$ 

   does it always hold that $\lim_{i\to \infty} \sum_n a_n(i)=\sum_n a_n$?

I have tried to construct counter examples, but each of them failed at item 2). For instance $a_n(i)=\frac{n}{i}$ then $\lim_{i\to \infty}a_n(i)= 0$, but for all $i$ fixed $\sum_n a_n(i)=\infty$, so $\lim_{i\to \infty} \sum_n a_n(i)=\infty$ i.e. 2) is not satisfied.

Another way to think about this is the following:
**We know that if $a_i\to a$ and $b_i\to b$ then $a_i+b_i\to a+b$ as $i\to \infty$ (if, $|a|,|b|< \infty $). But does it hold that the if the infinite sum of converging sequence is convergent then it converges to the sum of limits of each sequence (provided that each of those limits is finite)?**

I believe that result is quite trivial but I have been stuck on this part for a couple of days, so any help/input would be apricated!

Answer (score 1):

No, what you need here is [uniform convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence).

Counterexample: say that $a_n(n) = 1$ and $a_n(i) = 0$ if $i \neq 1$. Then $a_n(i) \to_i a_n = 0$, $\sum_n a_n(i) = 1$, but $\sum_n a_n = 0$.